# Append vector to 3d matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, append

I wish to append a row-vector (and later, also a column vector) to an existing **x** by **y** by **z** matrix. So basically "Add a new row (at the "bottom") for each z in the original 3d matrix. Consider the following short Matlab program

```
appendVector = [1 2 3 4 5]; % Small matrix for brevity. Actual matrices used are much larger.
origMatrix   = ones(5,5,3);
appendMatrix = [origMatrix( ... ); appendVector];
```

My question is: How do I adress (using Matlab-style matrix adressing, not a "manual" C-like loop) origMatrix( ... ) in order to append the vector above? Feel free to also include a suggestion on how to do the same operation for a column-vector (I am thinking that the correct way to do the latter is to simply use the '-operator in Matlab).

Comment: How exactly do you intend to append a 5-element vector to a 3D matrix. You would need a `1 x 5 x 3` array because you need to fill the third dimension.

Comment: @Suever I assumed that as part of the eventual solution. Is there a way to perform this operation using only a vector (by having Matlab take care of additional dimensions) or do I have to "prepare" the appended vector to instead be a 3d array (as per your suggestion above) prior to appending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "row" in a 3D matrix is actually a multi-dimensional array.

```
size(origMatrix(1,:,:))
%   5   3
```

So to append a row, you would need to append a `5 x 3` array.

```
toAppend = rand(5, 3);
appendMatrix = cat(1, origMatrix, toAppend);
```

You *could* append just a 5 element vector and specify an index for the third dimension. In this case, the value for the "row" for all other indices in the third dimension would be filled with zeros.

```
appendVector = [1 2 3 4 5];
origMatrix = ones(5,5,3);

appendMatrix = origMatrix;
appendMatrix(end+1, :, 1) = appendVector;
```

If instead, you want to append the same vector along the third dimension, you could use `repmat` to turn your vector into a `1 x 5 x 3` array and then append that.

```
appendVector = repmat([1 2 3 4 5], 1, 1, size(origMatrix, 3));
appendMatrix = cat(1, origMatrix, appendVector);
```

Comment: Wonderful.

Spot on.

Comment: A short note regarding your segment on the use of repmat. The code you present gives the error: 
"Error using cat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent."

I have not investigated why that is since the prior suggestion (not using repmat) was sufficient to solving my problem.